# How to write MS Excel formula to calculate 'Grand Total' per Client dynamically based on ClientName column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have attached my problem image and in that I am trying to achieve "Grand Total (₹)" value per client Name. I need to sum all values in 'Total Cost (₹)' column of Client 1 up to Client2 row and display the calculated value in J11 cell.

Similarly for Client 2, need to display the "Grand Total (₹)" value in J19 cell and so on. Rows between Client 1 and Client 2 are dynamic and can add any time but still need to calculate "Grand Total (₹)".

[image]

Comment: Your spreadsheet format is irregular and will make this task much harder. You should include all the data for a given row in that row. i.e., don't leave "ClientName" blank for any row that has data for that client.

Comment: Did the solution below work? @sekhar

Answer (score 1):

Follow this steps:

1. Fill in the Column B, with Client 1,Client 2, Client 3 etc (i.e. don't have blanks) - you can do this step fast if you google how to fill cells with previous values (**you can use the link below**):

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/05/02/fill-blanks-excel/

2. In column J (Grand Total) type in J11:

```
J11 = SUMIF($B$11:$B$100,B11,$I$11:$I$100) # Note that you can change the 100 to be the last row
```

and drag the formula down. I think this should get you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would make a pivot table from that data. Firstly in every row in column Client Name fill a customer name like on picture 1:

[image: Picture 1]

Then create pivot table like that one:

[image: Picture 2]